# Should I store openid claimed_id encrypted?

Tags: encryption, openid

Does the OpenID claimed_id of a user need to be encrypted when stored in a database? If someone had plain view access to it, could they pose as that user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The claimed_id is a lot like a username. It identifies the user according to their provider.

So, if someone gained access to a claimed_id, it would not be possible to pose as that user unless the attacker also had the password, or the user was already logged in on the attacker's system (or the attacker was able to subvert the login process some other way).

So, you can treat it like a username; encryption is not required, but you may feel better knowing it's there as an extra layer of security.

If someone gains direct access to your database, however, it's likely that they could compromise your entire site through other means.

Comment: If I hash a value with Sha256 without any secret key, wouldn't it take ages to get that value or generate a collision? That should be reasonably secure.

Comment: @möter: Hmm, yeah I wasn't thinking about hashing, only encryption. That's a good point! I'll remove the part about the attacker likely being able to reverse encryption if they have access to your server, however you'd probably still have bigger problems if the attacker gets access to your server ;-)

Comment: That's definitely something I want to avoid in the first place :D

Comment: @möter – If you log in users based on a hash of their claimed ID, an attacker might attempt to find a hash collision with a claimed ID under his control. That would allow him to impersonate the user without compromising either your site or the user's OpenID provider.

Comment: @aaz: That's a good argument for salting the hashes, then. But how likely is it that an attacker might gain access to *only* the database?

Comment: @Cameron – It's actually an argument against hashing. My claimed ID is distinct from all other possible claimed IDs, and I can only assert ownership of it on that basis. It is also public and often static, so you don't need to access the database to get it – all you need is to own [a popular site](http://xkcd.com/792/).

Comment: @aaz: Ah, I misunderstood your point about collisions the first time around. Excellent link by the way :D

Comment: @aaz: That sort of login scheme would defeat the whole purpose of OpenID. Also, requiring the user to enter their claimed_id in a form field is more than uncomfortable, they can be over 2000 chars long, iirc.

Comment: @möter – The user might enter a short URL that redirects to their claimed ID or an XRI, but in the end you get the normalized claimed ID. I was only talking about what you do with it when you get it to find the relevant user account: comparing it against claimed IDs in your database – good, comparing its hash against hashes of claimed IDs – iffy.

Comment: @aaz: You make a valid point. But an attacker a) needs to know the OpenId of a potential victim using your service b) ensure he gets to generate a claimed ID under his control that happens to hash to the same value as that of the victim. Quite impossible if you assume the hash function is SHA256 or the like.